# Python Webservice Call with Windows Authentication on

Tags: python, windows, web-services, authentication

I am noob at python, but now I have to create a sample python (v2.7) code for my webservice call. It seems working, but when I switched on the "Windows Authentication" on IIS for this webapp, it stopped working. I used SUDS library. Please help to add auth info for calling my webservice. Thanks in advance!

```
import suds
import urllib2
import logging
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
from suds.client import Client

##*************************************************************************
wsdlloc = 'http://myserver.com/myWebService.asmx'
wsdlurl = wsdlloc+'?wsdl'
login="test"
pwd="test123"
##*************************************************************************
if True:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger('suds').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
##-------------------

##--- IT IS WORKING WHEN NO WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION IS NEEDED
if False:
    c = Client(url=wsdlurl)
    list = c.service.myFunc("2014-05-08","2014-05-28")
    print( list )

##--- IT GENERATES "suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized"
if True:
    trnsport = suds.transport.http.HttpAuthenticated(username=login, password=pwd)
    client = Client(url=wsdlurl, username=login, password=pwd, transport=trnsport)
    list = client.service.myFunc("2014-05-08","2014-05-28")
    print( list )
```

Answer (score 1):

WindowsHttpAuthenticated(..) must be used, not HttpAuthenticated(...)  :( sorry for my noob question.